# Running thehive4 as a cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, akka

I'm trying to create a cluster of the thehive4 on K8s. From the Documentation [here](https://docs.thehive-project.org/thehive/installation-and-configuration/architecture/3_nodes_cluster/), the deployment is done on servers which is different. There is non official helm chart [here](https://github.com/jaredjennings/helm-thehive), but it is not what I'm looking for.

I created this deployment manifest and successfully created thehive nodes on Kuberenetes, but they are still not acting as a cluster since the `application.conf` file is not setup correctly.

Has anyone tried this before or has a similar experience with it, please share any documentation or usefull support to finish the setup.

Thank you in advance.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: thehive-config
data:
  application.conf: |
    
    # configuration example using servers not k8s

    akka {
      cluster.enable = on 
      actor {
        provider = cluster
      }
    remote.artery {
      canonical {
        hostname = "<My IP address>"
        port = 2551
      }
    }
    # seed node list contains at least one active node
    cluster.seed-nodes = [
                          "akka://[email protected]<Node 1 IP address>:2551",
                          "akka://[email protected]<Node 2 IP address>:2551",
                          "akka://[email protected]<Node 3 IP address>:2551"
                        ]
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: thehive-claim1
  name: thehive-claim1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1G
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: thehive-claim2
  name: thehive-claim2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1G
status: {}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: thehive
  name: thehive
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: thehive
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: thehive
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - --no-config
            - --no-config-secret
          image: thehiveproject/thehive4:latest
          name: thehive4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/thehive/application.conf
              subPath: application.conf
              name: config-volume
            - mountPath: /opt/thp/thehive/data
              name: thehive-claim1
            - mountPath: /opt/thp/thehive/index
              name: thehive-claim2
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: thehive-config
        - name: thehive-claim1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: thehive-claim1
        - name: thehive-claim2
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: thehive-claim2
status: {}
```